# How do I get Civilization 3 to play on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I can not get Civilization 3 to load onto ubuntu.  How can this be done. It is a windows based version.

Answer (score 3):

First things first: Your Windows version of Civ 3 is not going to work out of the box on Linux (or any other Operating System outside Windows) because it's a *Windows* version. That said, there are a couple of workarounds that you can try to run Windows programs on Linux:

1. Depending on the Civilization 3 version you have, you may get good or bad results using Wine: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=426
2. In any case, for installing and playing Windows games on Linux I'd recommend using PlayOnLinux: https://www.playonlinux.com/en/

Comment: The primary advantage of using PlayOnLinux is that it lets you choose, and easily change, what Wine version you're using.  I have games that will only run well on a single version of Wine out of all the releases in the past however long -- and other Windows programs that work pretty well in all of them.  PlayOnLinux also simplifies getting the correct Wine add-ons in place, and makes it easy to use different combinations for different programs.

Comment: I installed WINE unter Lubuntu 16.04 and sucessfully installed Civilization III Game of the Year. However, the game won't run afterwards. This is weird because the Editor that is also inclueded in the game does work. I wonder which setup should be used for Civ. Since it is a game that would run under Windows XP I suspect there need to be adjustments - maybe using winetricks. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ben, I'd advise you to check your Wine version, often changing from a staging to a stable version solves this kind of issue. In any case, I believe your question deserves its own post on Askubuntu, so we can better record proposed and accepted solutions.

Comment: Thanks! http://askubuntu.com/questions/876265/how-to-run-civilization-iii-game-of-the-year-edition-under-lubuntu-16-04-in-wi