# How to run Civilization III (Game of the Year Edition) under Lubuntu 16.04 in WINE?

Tags: lubuntu, wine, games

I installed WINE (stable, from the Ubuntu repository) Version 1.6.2 unter Lubuntu 16.04 and sucessfully installed Civilization III Game of the Year from DVD. However, the game won't run afterwards. This is weird because the Editor that is also inclueded in the game does work. I wonder which setup should be used for Civ. Since it is a game that would run under Windows XP I suspect there need to be adjustments - maybe using winetricks.

This is the output when using terminal to run:

('keine Berechtigung' means 'no permission')

I found [here](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?/topic/19378-device-not-found-wine/) that "Wine has to present the drives via ASPI and I guess translate I/O into the native Linux format. For some reason, that doesn't seem to be working properly on your setup."

```
ben@Shuttle:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Infogrames/Civilization III$ wine start Civilization3.exe
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
ben@Shuttle:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Infogrames/Civilization III$ fixme:aspi:SendASPI32Command ASPI: Partially implemented SC_HA_INQUIRY for adapter 0.
fixme:aspi:SendASPI32Command ASPI: Partially implemented SC_HA_INQUIRY for adapter 1.
err:aspi:SCSI_OpenDevice Failed to open device /dev/sg1: Keine Berechtigung
fixme:aspi:SendASPI32Command ASPI: Partially implemented SC_HA_INQUIRY for adapter 2.
err:aspi:SCSI_OpenDevice Failed to open device /dev/sg2: Keine Berechtigung
fixme:aspi:SendASPI32Command ASPI: Partially implemented SC_HA_INQUIRY for adapter 3.
fixme:aspi:SendASPI32Command ASPI: Partially implemented SC_HA_INQUIRY for adapter 4.
err:aspi:SCSI_OpenDevice Failed to open device /dev/sg4: Keine Berechtigung
```

Comment: Did you have a look at *freeciv* which is available in your ubuntu software repository?

Comment: Do you have access to a computer with a recent version of Windows and can you play the game on it? The reason for that question is that Windows made a DRM change that "bricks" certain games. So if it does not work under Windows, it may not work under Wine. You may want to try FreeCiv as an alternate. https://play.freeciv.org/

Comment: Try running the game from the terminal, it usually gives you some useful pre-crash information which you can use to look for an answer on the Internet.

Comment: thanks, I added the terminal output. I can play this game under windows xp, yes.

Comment: You'll probably get terrible graphics performance, but you could also try running it in a Windows VM.

Comment: I want to run it in WINE. graphics are okay in VM. but I am sure it should work in WINE and I want to find out what's the problem. I think it might be related to drives. I ran winecfg and related the .exe to Win XP. still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My error messages probably referred to the USB-CD/DVD-Drive I used. On a Laptop (MacbookPro8,3 from 2011, Lubuntu 16.04) with built-in drive the game works out of the box.

It does not work on my Shuttle Barebone PC with two Apple cinema displays hooked to it. Probably a graphics card/driver issue (after the NoCD-patch is applied the /dev/sg0-messages are gone).

It does also not work on my Acer Aspire One D270 with Lubuntu 14.04, I think because of lacking DirectX-support, although there is no message in terminal (as in the Shuttle case).

My game is a German one, probably version `1.16`. This is labeled "garbage" on [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=426) but with older versions of WINE. It now works on the old MacbookPro with Lubuntu 16.04, although I have not been testing longer term.

A good page for finding patches relating to different versions of the game is this: https://www.civ-wiki.de/wiki/Versionen_(Civ3).

A summary of patches including an official NoCD-patch is in the downloadlink at the bottom of the page [here](http://www.pcgames.de/Civilization-3-Spiel-20090/News/Probleme-mit-Civ-3-Vollversion-Hier-gibts-Abhilfe-401682/).

I first applied the patch for `1.29f` and then copied the `Civilization3.exe` from the `Civilization 3 PC Games Patch ohne Conquest von v1.21f (d).zip` into my directory.

Now, the game runs without CD.

To fix a graphics issue after the intro (cropped screen) I unchecked two options in `winefcg` under `graphics`: allow `decoration` and `control` by window manager. I also run it in Win XP mode.